# Font in *.txt file different

Tags: fonts, notepad++

I have been using Notepad++ for years. I always thought that copied text could only show up one size. I pasted some text from a chat transcript I need to parse and got different sizes and even fonts. How can you I change this and make just like text usually is? see link pic. Thanks
[See the pic example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feAD9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Edit` then `Paste Special` and choose html

Comment: Nothing happens when I do that. No text gets pasted. Thanks

Comment: I found a character in Word that Notepad++ cannot see. ⁠⁠⁠⁠Wow I did not know this is possible.